# Evaluate the following teleportation equation for $U = ZX$ and $a = 0, b = 0$

Tags: entanglement, mathematics, teleportation

When I evaluate the following equation using $U = ZX$ and $a = 0, b = 0$ [for Bell state], I am getting LHS not equal to RHS.

> Before describing the protocol, let us first review the teleportation protocol and introduce the notation used in the paper. In general, Bell states are of the following form
>
> $$|B_{xy}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|0,x\rangle + (-1)^y|1, x\oplus 1\rangle),\tag{1}$$
>
> where $x, y \in \{0, 1\}$ and $\oplus$ represents addition modulo $2$. The relationship between Bell states and classical bits can be defined as
>
> $$|B_{xy}\rangle \leftrightarrow xy, x, y \in \{0,1\} \tag{2}$$
>
> For any qubit $|\phi\rangle$ and any single-qubit unitary operation $U$, a general teleportation equation, based on an initial Bell state $|B_{ab}\rangle$, $a, b \in \{0, 1\}$, shared between the two users, can be written as
>
> $$\boxed{|\varphi\rangle_1 \otimes (I\otimes U)|B_{ab}\rangle_{2,3} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\mathrm{x\in\{0,1\}}}\sum_{\mathrm{x\in\{0,1\}}}(-1)^{b.x}|B_{x,y}\rangle_{1,2}\otimes UZ^{y\oplus b}X^{x\oplus a}|\varphi\rangle} \tag{3}$$
>
> where $X = (|0\rangle\langle 1| + |1\rangle\langle 0|)$, $Z = (|0\rangle\langle 0| - |1\rangle\langle 1|)$ and the subscripts denote different systems.

[Paper Reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.04438)

Comment: If the above equation is wrong.. what should be the correct equation?

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8303/55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a mistake. It's incorrect even for $a=0,b=0,U=I$. In this case the correct formula is 
$$
|\phi\rangle \otimes |B_{00}\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \bigg(|B_{00}\rangle \otimes |\phi\rangle + |B_{01}\rangle \otimes Z|\phi\rangle + |B_{10}\rangle \otimes X|\phi\rangle + |B_{11}\rangle \otimes XZ|\phi\rangle\bigg)
$$
but their formula swaps $X$ and $Z$ in the last term. 
It looks like if we swap $X$ and $Z$ terms in their formula then it will be correct (I checked on the computer).

**Update**

The correct formula is with the swapped $X$ and $Z$ terms:
$$
|\phi\rangle \otimes (I \otimes U)|B_{ab}\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \bigg(\sum_{x \in \{0,1\}}\sum_{y \in \{0,1\}} (-1)^{b\cdot x}|B_{xy}\rangle \otimes UX^{x\oplus a}Z^{y\oplus b}|\phi\rangle\bigg)
$$

I've used Julia programming language to check this. Note that both sides of equality are linear on $|\phi\rangle$, so we can check it only for $\phi = 0$ and $\phi = 1$. Also both sides are linear on $U$, so we can check equality only for $I, X, Z$ and $XZ$.

```
using LinearAlgebra

const ⊗ = kron
const ⊕(x,y) = (x+y) % 2

const Z = zeros(2,2) + [1 0; 0 -1]
const X = zeros(2,2) + [0 1; 1 0]
const Id = zeros(2,2) + I

function basis(x)
  return Id[:,x+1]
end

function bell(x,y)
  ret = zeros(4)    
  ret += basis(0) ⊗ basis(x)
  ret += (-1)^y * basis(1) ⊗ basis(x ⊕ 1)
  ret /= sqrt(2)
  return ret
end

function check()
  for a=0:1, b=0:1, ϕ=0:1, U in [Id, X, Z, X*Z]
    lhs = basis(ϕ) ⊗ ( (Id ⊗ U) * bell(a,b) )
    rhs = zeros(8)
    for x=0:1, y=0:1
      rhs += (-1)^(b*x) * bell(x,y) ⊗ (U * X^(x⊕a) * Z^(y⊕b) * basis(ϕ))
    end
    rhs /= 2
    err = norm(lhs - rhs)    
    println(err)
  end  
end

check()
```

Note that this check is numerical, though one can also try to use symbolic math packages, like SymPy.

Comment: could you please share the related code used for checking the equation...

Comment: yes, updated the answer